# Como mostrar un formulario en Symfony desde una consulta a 2 entidades

Tags: symfony3, symfony, dql

Tengo el siguiente código que funciona:

```
//AdminController.php
$orders_repo=$em->getRepository("BackendBundle:Orders");
$order=$orders_repo->getQuery()->getResult();
$form = $this->createForm(OrderType::class, $order);
```

Y en el formulario OrderType este código:

```
$builder
        ->add('customername', TextType::class, array(
                'label'=>'Numero de Causa',
                'required'=>'Requerido',
                'attr'=> array (
                    'class' => 'form-name form-control'
                )
            ));
```

El problema es cuando se quiere mostrar una consulta más elaborada para mostrar en el formulario.

Algo como esto:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
'SELECT u, o
                FROM BackendBundle:Orders o
                JOIN o.users u
    where o.orderid = :orderid'
 )->setParameter('orderid', $id);

 $order = $query->getResult();
 $form = $this->createForm(OrderType::class, $order);
```

¿Si se quiere mostrar esto en el formulario para luego actualizar como se puede hacer?

Answer (score 1):

En este caso deberías utilizar `EntityType`, previamente con la entidad `User` relacionada con tu entidad `Orders`.

Quedándote algo como lo siguiente:

```
$builder
        ->add('customername', TextType::class, array(
                'label'=>'Numero de Causa',
                'required'=>'Requerido',
                'attr'=> array (
                    'class' => 'form-name form-control'
                )
            ));
        ->add('user', EntityType::class, array(
              'class' => 'BackendBundle:User',
              'placeholder' => 'Escoge un usuario...',
              'choice_label' => 'nombre',
              'query_builder' => function(\BackendBundle\Entity\User $er) {
                     return $er->getUsersComoQuieras();
              }
        ));
```

EntityType normalmente genera un select en el que puedes escoger las entitdades (usuarios en tu caso) dentro del formulario. Puedes consultar la [documentación de EntityType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html), como verás en el ejemplo el uso de `query_builder` es opcional, puedes utilizarlo si quieres que el select tenga unos usuarios específicos según tu consulta o no utilizarlo para que te saque todos. Los campos `choice_value` y `choice_label` son para decirle de donde sacará el valor y la etiqueta que se mostrará en cada option del select.